# Safari 5.1 can NOT play HTTP Live Streaming (m3u8 file)

Tags: safari, http-live-streaming

This is my html file, it can play at Safari 5.0.5 (Mac OS X 10.6.8), but when I update the Safari to version 5.1, it can NOT play, can anyone tell me why, and how to solve it in Safari 5.1? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head> 
  <title>HTTP Live Streaming</title>
</head>

<body>
<video controls src="http://mysite/index.m3u8">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

**Updated:** I found the solution! When I set in the System Preference > Network > Advanced > proxies > Automatic Proxy Configuration with the proxy I use, I found the HTTP Live Streaming can NOT play, when I remove proxy, it can play now! How does this happen? Why it play well in Safari 5.0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Safari 5.1, open the Activity window with the Window->Activity menu.  That will show you all the URLs it attempts to download as well as whether it downloads successfully.  Maybe this will give you a clue.

Also look at the system console by running the Console app that you will find in /Applications/Utilities.

Try it in FireFox, Chrome, and on Windows, Internet Explorer and Safari for Windows.

If all those other browsers play your video OK, and neither the Activity window nor the console yield any insight, file [a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com/).  The chances are pretty good that, if it is a bug, Apple will fix it in the next release, or if it is not a Safari bug, an Apple engineer will give you a clue as to what you did wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I file a bug report, and the engineer of Apple said that they will fix it in next release. Thank you.